# Automatically resize/grow a kubernetes PVC

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to define a Persistent Volume in kubernetes which can grow automatically if it runs out of space?
If not, are there any extensions/workarounds, other than over-provisioning storage to protect our applications?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/

Comment: @EmilePels I think that refers to the existing ability to expand PVs, rather than have them expand themselves? "This feature allows users to easily resize an existing volume by editing the PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) object." The functionality I'm hoping for would not involve editing the PVC to resize the underlying volume, it would resize itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with an controller called the [Kubernetes Volume Autoscaler](https://github.com/DevOps-Nirvana/Kubernetes-Volume-Autoscaler).  This will require that you have defined your `StorageClasses` with the flag of `allowVolumeExpansion` enabled and that you have Prometheus installed.  It will also require that your disk controller supports hot-expansion, and your cloud provider supports it.  See the README on this repo for more information on this.

I can confirm this tool works perfectly on both AWS and Google Cloud's Kubernetes clusters.

**Disclaimer**: I authored this, but it is open source and now has a handful of contributors.

Answer (score 1):

The storage provider should support the volume expansion.

Enable the below property in the storage class

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

Edit the pvc definition and update the storage size. Kubernetes takes care of resizing the pvc volume automatically whenever the pod(s) referencing your volume are restarted.

Follow the below link for further help
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/

Comment: Thanks, I tested this out on an AWS EFS storage class, and it works great. I had misunderstood that article to be referring to manual expansion of PVCs. But it does allow the pod to use more than the specified capacity without issue. Ie I can set the capacity of my PVC to 50Mi, and a pod can use 100 Mi without issue. The PVC doesn't seem to resize, ie the capacity stays listed as 50Mi, but the pods can use more storage happily. Working great, thankyou!

Comment: @Jethro That's because is actually to allow manual expansion. The only reason it works is because EFS is not using the capacity option, see the note here 

`Since EFS is an elastic file system it doesn't really enforce any file system capacity. The actual storage capacity value in persistent volume and persistent volume claim is not used when creating the file system. However, since the storage capacity is a required field by Kubernetes, you must specify the value and you can use any valid value for the capacity.`

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver#features-1

Comment: allowVolumeExpansion is not automatic

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer you can't grow a PV if that is EBS type automatically.

If you want to grow over time use EFS PV which is NFS based. For some reason you want to stick to EBS(block-based) Then you have to create a simple script that will monitor uses and if it hit specific utilization it will update PVC claim to increase volume.